# Action ReactJs using Alt

Tags: reactjs, alt

I'm building a first App with Reactjs and I also use Alt library to implement Flux Model.
I have a ploblem, I tried to fix it, but It didn't work.
Here is my code:

```
import alt from '../alt';
class AddUserActions {
constructor() {
 this.generateActions(
  'addUserSuccess',
  'addUserFail'
  );}
   addUser(payload)
    {    
      $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'/api/user',
      data:{username:payload.username,
        password:payload.password,
        fbId:payload.fbId         
      }
    })
   .done((data) => {   
     this.actions.addUserSuccess(data.message);
    })
   .fail((jqXhr) =>{
   this.actions.addUserFail(jqXhr.responseJSON.message);
    });
  }
 }
 export default alt.createActions(AddUserActions);
```

Here, localserver response with data.message is "Successful", status 200. Ploblem occurs in `this.actions.addUserSuccess(data.message);`.
Error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addUserSuccess' of undefined`
I didn't know why. Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

`this.generateActions` isn't doing anything...You should be using `alt.generateActions(...)`

Also, it doesn't hurt to extract the addUserSuccess and addUserFail actions out on their own like this :

```
import Api from '../services/QuestionApi';

class QuestionActions {
    constructor() {
        // put auto generate actions here
    }

    getQuestions() {
        Api.getQuestions().then((result) => {
            this.getQuestionsSuccess(result);
        });
        return true;
    }

    getQuestionsSuccess(data) {
        return data;
    }

    createQuestion(question,state) {
        Api.createQuestion(question).then((result) => {
            this.createQuestionSuccess(result);
        });
        return true;
    }

    createQuestionSuccess(data) {
        this.getQuestions();
        return data;
    }


}
export default (alt.createActions(QuestionActions));
```

This will allow you to carry out any other functionality in the action if needed.